# edit specific column of recarray

Tags: python, arrays, datatables, recarray

I have a table in [FITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FITS) format that I have to edit.
This is a  sample of the data in Python:

```
data =
FITS_rec([(   0, -1, -1., -540., -1.93287335e-18, -0.14582774, -1., -26.5, 12.12002624, 4),
          (   1, -1, -1., -539., -2.19318337e-18, -0.16850733, -1., -26.5, 12.12002624, 4),
          (   2, -1, -1., -538., -2.18309714e-18, -0.16215905, -1., -26.5, 12.12002624, 4),
          ...,
          (1077, -2, -1.,  537.,  4.93990773e-18,  0.34313738, -1., -10. , 12.92693756, 5),
          (1078, -2, -1.,  538.,  3.57624176e-18,  0.25193304, -1., -10. , 12.92693756, 5),
          (1079, -2, -1.,  539.,  1.57228526e-18,  0.11302811, -1., -10. , 12.92693756, 5)],
         dtype=(numpy.record, [('ID', '>i4'), ('BIN_ID', '>i4'), ('X', '>f8'), ('Y', '>f8'), ('FLUX', '>f8'), ('SNR', '>f8'), ('XBIN', '>f8'), ('YBIN', '>f8'), ('SNRBIN', '>f8'), ('NSPAX', '>i4')]))
```

I want to edit the last column of each array, so that it correlates to `NSPAX`.
In order to delete the last column, I tried this code:

```
names = list(data.dtype.names)
new_names = names[:8]
b = a[new_names]
```

But I get this error when running it: `IndexError: only integers, slices (':'), ellipsis ('...'), numpy.newaxis ('None') and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Can someone help me? Also, once I've deleted that column, how can I add another one?